# Spring batch with task executor does not run in parallel

Tags: spring, task, spring-batch, executorservice

I have a spring batch config as follows:

```
<beans>
<bean id="taskExecutor"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="25"/>
</bean>

<batch:job id="springJobBatch1">
        <batch:step id="step1" >
            <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor">
                <batch:chunk reader="Reader1" writer="Writer1" commit-interval="1000" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="Listener1"/>
        </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
<bean id="Reader1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">            
       <property name="dataSource" ref="testdsref1" />
       <property name="queryProvider">
              <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
               <property name="dataSource" ref="testdsref1" />
                  <property name="selectClause" value="select..."/>
                  <property name="fromClause" value="from..."/>
                  <property name="whereClause" value="where..."/>
                  <property name="sortKey" value="order..." />
             </bean>
        </property>            
        <property name="pageSize" value="1000"/>
        <property name="saveState" value="false"/>
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="testmapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="testRunJob1" class="package1.anyClass.thread1">
        <property name="cache" ref="testdsref2"/>
        property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
        <property name="reader" ref="springJobBatch1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao"/>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="Thread1" class="java.lang.Thread">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Runnable" ref="testRunJob1" ></constructor-arg>
</bean>    
<bean id="Thread2" class="java.lang.Thread">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Runnable" ref="testRunJob2" ></constructor-arg>
</bean>   

<bean id="TheChosenOneThread" init-method="initMethod">
        <property name="thread1" ref="Thread1"/>
        <property name="thread2" ref="Thread2"/>
</bean>   
</beans>

public class TheChosenOneThread{
thread1 t1;
thread2 t2;

public void initMethod(){
    ExecutorService t1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBEROFTHREADS);
    executor.execute(t1);
    executor.execute(t2);
    executor.shutdown();
    try{
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("cache restart timed-out.");
    }

}
```

Expected:
The requirement is to make sure that the Thread1 and Thread2 executes in parallel 
and the server should start only after it completes.
Actual:

When the server starts, all the beans gets initialized.Along with it, "TheChosenOneThread" thread's initMethod also gets executed.
but The threads t1 and t2 stuck along with the main server thread and the server never starts.
Please suggest me a simpler way as well if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be manually creating threads and calling the executor. Set the `executorService` of the `SimpleJobLauncher`, and call `runJob` with your two jobs. They'll run in parallel because the `executorService` has more than 1 thread. (And you can remove your Thread1 and Thread2 beans.)

To check completion, either periodically check the returned `JobExecution`s from `runJob`, or use a `JobExecutionListener`.

Comment: I couldn't understand your last statement. Could you please look into the 2nd answer that i have put after few changes that were suggested?